# Latent variable model from measure theory perspective

Tags: machine-learning, probability-theory

It's common in machine learning papers to see things like $p(x,z|\theta)$ or $p(x|z)$. Where $x$ is usually the data vector, $z$ the latent vector and $\theta$ the model parameter, like network weights.

However is there a way to make sense of these notations from measure theory's perspective? Perhaps $(x,z,\theta)$ is a random vector from some joint measurable space.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need measure theory to understand that notation.  Measure theory doesn't really add anything.

That said: Yes, you can in the same way that you can understand probabilities via measure theory, regardless of whether they come from machine learning or anything else.  See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4748560/14578, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/393712/14578, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/393712/14578.

The interpretation is that $X,Z,\Theta$ are random variables; we have a joint distribution on $(X,Z,\Theta)$; and $p(x|z)$ is shorthand for either

- $\Pr[X=x|Z=z]$, for discrete distributions; or
- the probability density analog of that for continuous distributions, e.g., $f_{X|Z}(x|z)$ where $f$ is the [conditional density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) for $X$ conditioned on Z.

None of this requires measure theory, or benefits from measure theory, but I suppose you could describe it using measure theory if you wished.